# Symfony 1.4 Cache Dashboard for specific user

Tags: caching, google-analytics, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Not sure if anyone is still using the legacy 1.4 - but I love it!

**Background:**

- I have a user dashboard available at `app.com/home/dashboard`
- To optimize DB hits, I cached the template Since the URL doesn't have a user parameter, a user ended up seeing another user's data
- To beat this, I wrote a filter to include the user-id in the URL, giving each user their own URL like `app.com/home/18/dashboard`
- While this prevents the data leak and provides the benefit of caching, it is messing reporting in GA, since I cannot track the total visits to the Dashboard (directly)

Has anyone worked around this?

Comment: This sounds like you want to aggregate each user's unique dashboard visits into one total.  The Content Grouping feature might help you accomplish this  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem. To solve it I've decided to split the whole page into partials and components and cache those instead.

To make partials/component cached per-user just pass `'user_id' => $sf_user->getId()` along with parameters. That will make user_id value used as part of cache entry key.

Comment: Great thanks. I really wish we could apply something more generic.